# Regular experession finds SMTP Addresses needs to allow for more domain names

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

I have the below RegEx match string that matches most SMTP addresses very well.  Its been tested thoroughly and is known to perform well and also correctly match the vast majority of SMTP addresses whose domain extension (.com, .net ...) matches the list of extensions given in the match string (literally tested on more than 1 million SMTP addresses).

However, there are 2 problems.

1) At the time this was written, the list of extensions was the same as what you see at the end of the string.  Now, there are many more valid extensions, and that list is likely to keep growing.

2) I am a complete RegExp novice, and modifying this is outside of my league.  The same is true for all of my colleagues where I work.

I don't think it is practical to maintain this to match on *only* valid domain name extensions because there are just too many of them, and the list will continue to grow.  So, what I would like to do is modify it to allow for any extension that:

a) is between 2 and 6 characters.
b) contains only alpha characters.

If anyone thinks that I should consider changing my a) or b) to something else then I'm open to that feedback too.

This is used in a C# app.

Thanks in advance for the help.  Here it is:

```
    private const string MatchSmtpRegEx = @"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b";
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this non-capturing group matches the top level domain name:

```
(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)
```

It's matching any 2 capital letters or any of the options you see above.

You just need to change this part to fit your requirement. This is what you should change it to:

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,6})
```

A non-capturing group matching a-z or A-Z, 2 to 6 times.